# The mathematics of US visa bulletin

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I want to know how actually the visa-allocation process works in the US. I had asked a question for this where I got perfect answers but now I am having another related doubt so I am posting a new question.

Let's say that this is the dawn of America's independence and they just put in place an immigration system of the 21st century and that Indians, Chinese, Mexicans and all the rest of the world wants to immigrate to the US and all countries' nationals start their processes. In the first year, Indians, Chinese, Philipines and Mexicans reached per country cap. And let us assume that in total 15 countries reached the per country cap too. The UK, France and Sweden didn't reach the cap, so they would logically not have to wait in a queue, BUT, it seems they have to, as other countries have already used all the visas of that year by reaching their 7% limit (7% x 15 countries= 105%; so 15 countries far exceeded the visas available that year and didn't allow other low emigration country nationals like Sweden to immigrate to the US that year.)

This way, there are 2 types of queues. One is a country queue (governed by per country cap), and the other is the combined queue of countries like France, Sweden that could have got an immigrant visa immediately, but due to the dominance of India and China, have got their applications delayed for years (as for all years, high emigration countries **eat up** others' places by consuming their own full 7% limit to reach the annual visas available). So all the low emigration countries are placed in another queue called *all other chargeability areas**. And, this way, surprisingly, all other countries suffer almost the same backlog of their own common queue as India and China suffer with their Indian and Chinese queues.

Is this a true understanding of the United States immigration system and the backlog?

If not, please help me knowing:

(1) How many types of queues are there?

(2) Whether a person from Sweden can get an immigrant visa immediately after processing?

(3) What does the date on the "All other chargeability areas" signify? For countries like India, China and Mexico, it signifies the status of their priority dates coming nearer and how fast.
But what does the "All other chargeability areas" signify? A common queue for all countries minus oversubscribed countries? What is it?

Comment: This is a good question.  I don't know the details of how it works, but your hypotheses seems likely to be correct.  I suspect that user102008 will know the answer.  I replaced "green card" with "immigrant visa," because it is more precise, and I made a few other relatively minor changes to punctuation and grammar while I was in the editor.  The product of 7% and 20 is 140%, though.  I would have corrected this, but perhaps you would prefer to use 15 countries and 105%.

Comment: @phoog Thank you so much for your support and for editing this question. Sorry for the pathetic math mistake:-) How can we notify user102008 about this question?

Comment: I am sure that user102008 will see it sooner or later.

Comment: I actually don't know how the calculation works.